# CSS not rendering after rake assets:clobber

Tags: javascript, css, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been having issues precompiling assets when pushing to heroku. Particularly the little bit of javascript I have in my code at the moment. Based on some things I read I tried rake assets:clobber and then precompiled again. After doing so my CSS still exists in my code but the page renders nothing but the HTML in both production and development. I also tried deleting the browser cache as well as having somebody else access the app from another site which confirmed the same issues. I'm honestly not sure exactly what to show here as I don't really know where the issue lies so if you need to see anything else let me know. It seems everything is intact. I have yet to find a satisfactory answer to this issue and would appreciate some input. Thanks.

Some source code from production with errors

```
head:after {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: large;
            font-weight: bold;
            content: "Error compiling CSS asset";
          }

          body:before, body:after {
            font-family: monospace;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
          }

          body:before {
            font-weight: bold;
            content: "\000a Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after \0022 \002f *\0022 : expected \0022 \002f \0022 , was \0022 * This is a man...\0022 \000a   (in \002f app\002f app\002f assets\002f stylesheets\002f application.css)";
          }

          body:after {
            content: "\000a   (sass):1";
          }
```

custom.css.scss

@import "bootstrap";

/

```
* mixins, variables, etc. */

$grayMediumLight: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* universal */
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.center h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* typography */



h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 93px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}



.hero-unit {
padding: 60px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 200;
line-height: 30px;
color: inherit;
background-color: #eeeeee;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}


/* Header */



.btn-lg {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 20px;

}

.col-lg-6 {
width: 50%;
margin-top: 60px;
color: white;
}

#home-header {
background-image: url("firepit_80opac.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 841px;
display: block;
}

.header-description h2 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 93px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-shadow: 0 0px 12px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.55);
  padding: 0px 0 4px 0;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}




.navbar-inner ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 15px 10px;
}

.header-btn {
color: white;
margin: 0px auto;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 20%;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 24px;
padding: 20px 35px;
border: 2px solid rgb(219, 82, 47);
background: rgb(219, 82, 47);
display: block;
-webkit-border-radius: 9px;
border-radius: 9px;
text-align: center;
}



.header-btn:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}



.header-description {
  margin: 100px 0 80px;
}

.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

/* site header */


.nav li a {
  color: #db522f;
}

/* home-footer */


.row.home-footer {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgb(243, 243, 243);
  position: relative;
}


.col-md-4 {
  width: 33.3%;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.col-md-4 {
  color: rgb(124, 124, 124);
}

/* carousel */
#quote-carousel 
{
  padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

/* Control buttons  */
#quote-carousel .carousel-control
{
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  text-shadow: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
/* Previous button  */
#quote-carousel .carousel-control.left 
{
  left: -12px;
}
/* Next button  */
#quote-carousel .carousel-control.right 
{
  right: -12px !important;
}
/* Changes the position of the indicators */
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators 
{
  right: 50%;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: -19px;
}
/* Changes the color of the indicators */
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li 
{
  background: #c0c0c0;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators .active 
{
  background: #333333;
}
#quote-carousel img
{
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px
}
/* End carousel */

.item blockquote {
    border-left: none; 
    margin: 0;
}

.item blockquote img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item blockquote p:before {
    content: "\f10d";
    font-family: 'Fontawesome';
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}



/**
  MEDIA QUERIES
*/

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    #quote-carousel 
    {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding: 0 40px 30px 40px;
    }

}

/* Small devices (tablets, up to 768px) */
@media (max-width: 768px) { 

    /* Make the indicators larger for easier clicking with fingers/thumb on mobile */

    #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators {
        bottom: -20px !important;  
    }
    #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0px 5px;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
    }
    #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li.active {
        margin: 0px 5px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
    }
  }
```

production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` has moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: Rails.application.secrets.domain_name,
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
    password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
  }
  # ActionMailer Config
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => Rails.application.secrets.domain_name }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false


  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = false

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: Rails.application.secrets.domain_name,
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
    password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
  }
  # ActionMailer Config
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  # Send email in development mode?
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true


  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb mistake here. I accidentally deleted a character in my application.css file. Had a * instead of */.